# Nobe at SQL scripting. Please haalp

Tags: sql, anaconda, navigator, tbl

I am trying to access my table in SQL database. However, I am getting an unusual error. Can someone please help me I am very new at this.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
com = sqlite3.connect('Reporting.db')
```

**Note**: Panda dataframe is already defined above that's why I am not including this over here.

````
df.to_sql('tblReporting', com, index=False, if_exists='replace')
print('tblReporting loaded \n')```   

%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite:///Reporting.db
%%sql
SELECT *
FROM tblReporting
````

This is the error I am getting

> SELECT *
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**Note #2**: I am using Anaconda Navigator for writing scripts

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!! that's my Syntax

```
 import sqlite3    
 import pandas as pd  
 com = sqlite3.connect('Reporting.db')  
 df.to_sql('tblReporting', com, index=False, if_exists='replace')  
 print('tblReporting loaded \n')  
 org_query = '''SELECT * FROM tblReporting'''    
 df = pd.read_sql_query(org_query, com)  
 df.head()
```

**Note:** added ''' before and after my org_query helped me resolved this